# Failed add up elements in the array in parallel with several strides MPI

Tags: c, performance, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

I am trying to parallelly add up the elements from the array. I got an example for the algorithm that I follow to add up the elements with different strides in the array:

```
input = [3,10,1,22,8,28,4,53,4,4,0,4,0,0,0,57]

First Stride (Add every N/2^1 to N/2^1 + N/2^(1+1): 
input = [ 3,10,1,22,8,28,4,53,4,4,0,57,0,0,0,57]

Second Stride (Add every N/2^2 to N/2^2 + +N/2^(2+1):
input = [3,10,1,22,8,50,4,53,4,57,0,57,0,57,0,57]

Third Stride (Add every N/2^3 to N/2^3 + N/2^(3+1):
input = [3,10,11,22,30,50,54,53,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57]
```

I wrote the code to distribute the adding work equally to my processors. (To be noted that I am trying to avoid using MPI_Scan)

The processor each has a temp value which means the changed array value and `MPI_Gather` it back to root, then the root will change the whole input array and `MPI_cast` the input to each processor to do the adding work again before entering the next stride.

However, my result does not seem to work as I want. I would appreciate if anyone can tell me what I did wrong in my codes.

Here is my code: (Updated)

```
int DownPhaseFunction(int* input, int size_per_process, int rank, int totalarray, int size, int* Temp0)
{
    //rank is the id of processor
    //size is the total number of processors

    int temp =0;
    int index = 0;
    int index0 = 0;

    //First Stride
    if(rank == 0)
    {
      input[(totalarray)-(totalarray/2)+(totalarray/4)-1] += input[(totalarray)-(totalarray/2)-1];
    }

    MPI_Bcast(input,totalarray,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    //Start with Second Stride to the end
    for (int i=4 ; i<totalarray ; i*=2)
    {
    //if the number of elements to be changed is larger than total size of processors, do a few more strides
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j+=(size*totalarray/i))
    {
        index = ( (rank+1)*totalarray/i) + j;
        if (index != totalarray)
        {
            temp = input[(index+(totalarray/i)/2)-1] + input[index-1];
        }
        else
        {
            temp = input[index-1];
        }

        //Gather the changed elements back to root
        MPI_Gather (&temp, size , MPI_INT, Temp0, size, MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD );

        //Let root change the changed elements in the input array
        if(rank == 0)
            {
            for(int r=0; r<size; r++)
            {
            index0 = ((r+1)*totalarray/i)+j;

            if( (index0) != totalarray)
                {
                input[(index0+(totalarray/i)/2-1)] = Temp0[r];
                }

            }
            }

        //send it back to every processor to do the next stride
        MPI_Bcast(input,totalarray,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    }

    return(*input);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The processor each has a temp value which means the changed array
> value and MPI_Gather it back to root, then the root will change the
> whole input array and MPI_Bcast the input to each processor to do the
> adding work again before entering the next stride.

IMO this design complicates matters. I would suggest to first explicitly set boundaries of the `input` array range that each process is allowed to work. For an input of 16 it would be as follows:

```
Process 0 works from [0 to 4[
Process 1 works from [4 to 8[
Process 2 works from [8 to 12[
Process 3 works from [12 to 16[
```

to calculate those ranges one can use the following formula:

```
    int begin = rank * size_per_process;
    int end =  (rank + 1) * size_per_process;
```

To implement the remains logic we start by having a loop that begins by splitting the array in half, and for each iteration we keep splitting in halves.

```
    int split_size = totalarray/2;
    while(split_size > 1){
        //....
        split_size = split_size/2;
    }
```

We need an additional loop to iterate over `input` array using the current *split size*, namely:

```
        for(int i = split_size; i < totalarray; i+= split_size){
               //... 
        }
```

Each rank will only be allowed to work on the array interception assigned to that process, namely:

```
   for(int i = split_size; i < totalarray; i+= split_size){
       int dest = i + (split_size/2) - 1;
       if(begin <= dest && dest < end)
          input[dest] += input[i -1];
    }
```

A more improved (but less readable) version:

```
   int shift = (split_size/2) - 1;
   int dest = ((begin == 0) ? split_size : (split_size/begin) * split_size) + shift;
   for(; dest < end; dest += split_size)
      input[dest] += input[dest - shift -1];
```

After each stride all processes send their array interception to the other processes:

```
 MPI_Allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, size_per_process, MPI_INT, input, size_per_process, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

The [MPI_IN_PLACE](https://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/mpi-standard/mpi-report-2.0/node145.htm) ensures that the new `input` array (resulted from gathering the work done by all processes) replaces the old `input` array. For an input of 16 elements and 4 processes, the process 0, 1, 2, and 3 will send the elements [0 to 4[, [4 to 8[, [8 to 12[, and [12 to 16[ of their `input` arrays to all the other processes, respectively. Consequently, at the end of the `MPI_Allgather` call, every process has the most update `input` array with all the part that were changed by the processes during the current iteration.

So for the input = `[3,10,1,22,8,28,4,53,4,4,0,4,0,0,0,57]` with 4 processes the iterations will look like the following:

First stride:

```
Process 2 input[11] += input[7] (input[11] = 4 + 53)
```

input array: [3, 10, 1, 22, 8, 28, 4, 53, 4, 4, 0, **57**, 0, 0, 0, 57]

Second stride:

```
Process 1 input[5] += input[3] (input[5] = 28 + 22)
Process 2 input[9] += input[7] (input[9] = 4 + 53)
Process 3 input[13] += input[11] (input[13] = 0 + 57)
```

input array: [3, 10, 1, 22, 8, **50**, 4, 53, 4, **57**, 0, 57, 0, **57**, 0, 57]

Third stride:

```
2, Process 0 input[2] += input[1] (input[2] = 1 + 10)
2, Process 1 input[4] += input[3] (input[4] = 8 + 22)
2, Process 1 input[6] += input[5] (input[6] = 4 + 50)
2, Process 2 input[8] += input[7] (input[8] = 4 + 53)
2, Process 2 input[10] += input[9] (input[10] = 0 + 57)
2, Process 3 input[12] += input[11] (input[12] = 0 + 57)
2, Process 3 input[14] += input[13] (input[14] = 0 + 57)
```

input = [3, 10, **11**, 22, **30**, 50, **54**, 53, **57**, 57, **57**, 57, **57**, 57, **57**, 57]

A complete running example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

void printArray(int *array, int size){
     int rank;
     MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
     if(rank == 0){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            printf("%2d ", array[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int totalarray = 16;
    int rank, size;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int input[16] = {3,10,1,22,8,28,4,53,4,4,0,4,0,0,0,57}; 

    printArray(input, totalarray);

    int size_per_process = totalarray/size;
    int begin = rank * size_per_process;
    int end =  (rank + 1) * size_per_process;
    int split_size = totalarray/2;
    while(split_size > 1){
        int shift = (split_size/2) - 1;
        int dest = ((begin == 0) ? split_size : (split_size/begin) * split_size) + shift;
        for(; dest < end; dest += split_size)
            input[dest] += input[dest - shift -1];
        MPI_Allgather(MPI_IN_PLACE, size_per_process, MPI_INT, input, size_per_process, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        split_size = split_size/2;
    }
        
    printArray(input, totalarray);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

**Input :** `{3,10,1,22,8,28,4,53,4,4,0,4,0,0,0,57}`
**Output:** `{3,10,11,22,30,50,54,53,57,57,57,57,57,57,57,57}`

Bear in mind that this is a toy example of the proposed design; not bulletproof ready to use in production type of code.